# Shared Hosting Provider

Tags: web-hosting, looking-for-hosting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

I've been with Dreamhost for 5 years but the amount of downtime I have experienced over the last 6 months has been outrageous.

As of now (2012) which hosting provider would you recommend?  Most of my sites are small to medium readership blogs running WordPress.

I've been looking at Inmotion and Hostgator.  Reliability is paramount.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I am in the same boat as you, been with Dreamhost for 10 and while their support has been awesome their network problems are reaching unacceptable levels (reached not reaching, really).

There are thousands of hosts out there.  There are several webhosting review sites and forum (just google), but I suspect that some of them are a bit rigged for who provides the best affiliate kickbacks.

I have a friend who just left Dreamhost for JaguarPC and he's been very happy there.  Linode is great for a completely unmanaged solution, I've used them for several sites.

I'd pick a couple where the price fits your budget, the reviews are positive, and throw a site on each, and see how things go.